# Is it possible to have a dependent clause without an independent clause?

Tags: word-meaning, clauses

**Men whose experience could be called upon at need**.

I searched on Oxford Dictionary to find out the usage of *need*. It showed that to mean in an emergency *at need* can be used, and then the sentence stated above was used as an example to explain the meaning of *at need*. Unfortunately I cannot understand the meaning of this sentence. Because due to presence of *whose*, it seems to me that the above sentence is a dependent clause, of which independent clause was not mentioned.

[Source](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/need)

Comment: Dictionaries list examples that editors think can explain the meanings most effectively and they could be either a phrase/clause or sentence. In other words, not all examples are in independent clauses.

Comment: Noting [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+need&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20need%3B%2Cc0) showing the massive decline of what I consider to be an effectively *archaic* usage, I do not think it's worth the average learner bothering with it. Today it would almost always be replaced by ***as/if required/needed*** or similar.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I've just discovered that OP's cited example is from [oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/at-need), where it specifically says this usage is ***archaic***.

Comment: But the meaning of "at need" isn't the point of the question.

Comment: I'm really surprised that usage is listed as archaic. Sounds fine to me. In fact, I think I use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sentence can indeed be a dependent clause, which would be a noun phrase within the independent clause that is missing or not mentioned here. The phrase is used in the Oxford dictionary as an example in which *at need* can be used.

Here's an example of a complete sentence containing your dependent clause:

> They are **men whose experience could be called upon at need**.

The part in bold is your dependent clause, it functions as a complement to the subject in the main clause (*They are X*).

However, even though it is not a "complete" sentence, it is not wrong. It could for example serve as a short answer to a question:

> - What are you looking for?
> - Men whose experience could be called upon at need.

Answer (score 0):

Not every utterance has to be a descriptive sentence, command, question, etc. The above clause is a just noun phrase (a phrase which grammatically works like a noun in other clauses). It would be perfectly fine to say it , for example, as a response to "What kind of men are you looking to hire for the project?".